# grails: min constraint and attributes of BigDecimal type (type mismatch?)

Tags: grails, constraints, min

In the grails class, I have specified

```
BigDecimal  amount
```

to represent an amount of money in a transaction.

Then, in the constraints section, I specified:

```
amount      ( nullable:false, min : 100)
```

To indicate that the minimum amount accepted would be a dollar.  This compiles just fine, but runtime throws a type incompatibility error:

```
2011-10-26 15:17:06,116 [main] ERROR validation.ConstrainedProperty  - Exception thrown applying constraint [min] to class [class com.mycorp.mypkg.MyProprietaryDefinition] for value [100]: Parameter for constraint [min] of property [amount] of class [class  com.mycorp.mypkg.MyProprietaryDefinition] must be the same type as property: [java.math.BigDecimal]
```

So am I to safely assume that I cannot specify min values on BigDecimal attributes?

Thank you!

Alexx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grails expects the *min* and *max* values to be the same datatype as the associated property while the *scale* value is always required to be an Integer.  Casting to BigDecimal or adding .0 to the end of the value fixes the problem.

```
amount(nullable: false, min: 100.0, max: 9999.99, scale: 2)
```

I recently filed IntelliJ IDEA bug report [IDEA-75471](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-75471?projectKey=IDEA) about this very issue.  IDEA 10.5.2 incorrectly flags an inspection warning if the *min* and *max* values are not integer and the *scale* value is not the same datatype as the property.  The warning can be ignored using `//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck`.

Answer (score 2):

A groovy cast to the min value should also work.

```
 min: 0 as BigDecimal
```

or possibly

```
 min: 0G
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Any of the "min" values I specified on BigDecimal attributes were rejected.  I commented them all out, and deployed the app successfully.  I tried tacking on ".0" to the end of one min value, and the app rebuilt and redeployed.  One by one, I repeated this, save for the last commented min.  So then I uncommented it as it was, min : 0, and the app broke.

So I guess that is the answer, that if you don't have a decimal portion to your min (or max, I'd also assume), you need to add one.